# How to break lines in Input field via Development tools

Tags: html, css, printing

I need to perform a full PDF print of a website with a populated questionnaire. It's accessed via Chrome, but some fields contain extensive answers and they are partially cut as they do not fit within the line. The text can be extracted via copying, but it's not fully visible in a print (I'm sorry, I cannot provide a full picture).

[image]

To make the full contents visible in the print, I would like to break it into several lines. I heard that it could be done by adding the "word-wrap: break-word" or "overflow-wrap: break-word" properties, bit it appears that it's an Input field and, from what I heard, such fields are not breakable and I would need to change it to Textarea.

[image]

However, when I change the field type to Textarea, the contents of the field disappear.

[image]

[image]

Is there any relatively simple way to somehow make this field breakable and show full text which was previously provided as an input?

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` does not have a `title` attribute. That's why the text disapears. Try to insert the text like this: `<textarea>Text should be here</textarea>`.